# WebStorm + webpack.DefinePlugin = autocompletion?

Tags: webpack, autocomplete, webstorm

If I do smth like this in my webpack config:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    PropTypes: "prop-types",
  })
]
```

then how do I make WebStorm to not complain about "missing import statement" on global `PropTypes` variable in my code, and make autocompletion for it work?

Comment: what autocompletion are you looking for?

Comment: `PropTypes.{bool, func, string, ...etc}`, of course.

Comment: no way; webStorm can't know what properties to complete here. ` PropTypes` here is just a constant with string value. there is no magic allowing the IDE to figure out what properties to expect here

Comment: I hoped, smth like "Settings > Javascript > Libraries" can help here. Like mapping between variable and module. But thought I just can't configure it properly.

Comment: no, libraries just provide definitions for objects used in code. They don't tell the syntax analyser how to treat an arbitrary string literal